# Find the smallest root of the function $e^{-x} = \sin (x)$

Tags: functions, numerical-methods, roots

I have the following problem:

> Find the smallest root of the function $e^{-x} = \sin (x)$ and focus the root with Newton's method to $8$ decimal accuracy.

Any suggestions?

Comment: First let $f(x) = e^{-x} - sin(x)$ Now guess a root.  Newton states that if $x$ is an approximation to the root $x_n = x - \frac{f(x)}{f'(x)}$ is a better approximation.  Where are you having problems?

Comment: What have you tried - where did you get when you tried to apply Newton's method? Have you drawn a diagram showing $e^{-x}$ and $\sin x$ to get an understanding of what is going on?

Comment: @WarrenHill - I think there are infinite number of roots, how can you get the smallest one ?

Comment: I tried to solve $x$ from the equation $e^{-x} = sin(x)$, but it didn't seem like the right approach. @Belgi I think the problem means that I have to find the smallest value of $x$, which gives me $f(x) = 0$. So I should just throw a guess? Should I first sketch the function, find the approximate value of $x$ where $f(x) = e^{-x} - sin(x)$ achieves its $0$ value and then make this more accurate by using newton's method?

Comment: @jjepsuomi - I don't know how to get the smallest one, I tried using Taylor to approximate, $e^-x\approx 1-x$ and $\sin(x)=x$ to get $1-x=x$ and so $x=0.5$ is a guess. By Wolfram the difference is only 0.127 so a few iterations will give you a small root. But I can't say if there is a one smaller

Comment: @jjepsuomi sketching the two functions on the same graph will give you an idea of where they are equal and allow you to put some bounds on where the smallest root is - so if you have a root within those bounds it has to be the smallest one. Highly recommended to sketch two simple functions you do understand, rather than a more complicated function which you are not sure about.

Comment: @MarkBennet Thank you for your advices (and patience ;))! :) I will do that :)

Comment: @Belgi Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some hints.

1. Newton's method is a root-finding algorithm (i.e. given $f(x)$ it finds $x^{*}$ such that $f(x^{*}) = 0$) so you need to find a function $f(x)$ which has a root at the same point that $e^{-x} = \sin x$.
2. Newton's method will find a root close to your initial guess. Where do you think the smallest root may lie? [image]

Comment: As I commented to Warren,  I think there are infinite number of roots, how can you get the smallest one ?

Comment: I'll tikz up a better picture in a bit.

Comment: +1 Thnx, I get it now :) I think I can solve it now myself :) I will give it a shot. I just needed some directions. Appreciate the help!

Comment: And if the picture doesn't make it clear, try $x_{0} = 0$ as your first guess. The closest root is the smallest one.